# Get image from headless Pygame instance

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pygame, python-imaging-library

I'm working with game based on Pygame. In the abstract - I need to run it in headless mode. By now, I'm using:

```
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'dummy'
```

And the problem is, that I can't take the screen from game to NumPy array. The one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472781/in-pygame-how-can-i-save-a-screen-image-in-headless-mode) which I found actually works, but only with saving the image to the file, what totally misses the point - but maybe it is a hint. I've tried things like parsing Surface to string:

```
pil_string_image = pygame.image.tostring(screen,"RGBA",False)
im = Image.frombytes("RGBA",(400, 400), pil_string_image)       
cv2.imshow('screen', np.asarray(im))
```

but afterall I've got only grey screen and that's all.

The reason is, that I need to prepare the game to run in Collab or in text env because I'm doing ML things using game screen.

Is there any way to take the screen properly? Or maybe I could trigger the headless mode in another way, which lets me take image simply like that?

```
pygame.surfarray.array3d(pygame.display.get_surface())
```

Comment: You should be able to do `buffer = BytesIO()` then `pygame.image.save(..., buffer)` Something similar here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281257/2836621

Comment: Thanks, did that, but got errors:
'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start/continuation byte' and 'TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str''. Should I give some parameter to opened Buffer? I didn't tried to display that yet, those two instructions which you've given are throwing that errors.

Comment: Sorry, I’m not near a computer for next few days so I can’t work it out for you at the minute.

Comment: Okay, so I would try to do it by myself. Thanks for the effort! If you would have some brilliant idea please let me know :D

Answer (score 2):

It seems `screen` is a [pygame.surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object, presumably returned from `pygame.display.set_mode(..)`. You can call the [surfarray](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.array3d) methods using `screen` as the first argument.

E.g.

```
>>> import os
>>> import pygame
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
>>> WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 480
>>> os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"
>>> pygame.init()
(6, 0)
>>> screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
>>> screen.fill(pygame.color.Color("black"))
<rect(0, 0, 640, 480)>
>>> print(pygame.surfarray.array3d(screen)[0])
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
>>> pygame.draw.line(screen, pygame.color.Color("blueviolet"), (0,0), (0,480))
<rect(0, 0, 1, 481)>
>>> print(pygame.surfarray.array3d(screen)[0])
[[146  36 255]
 [146  36 255]
 [146  36 255]
 ...
 [146  36 255]
 [146  36 255]
 [146  36 255]]
```

Comment: I'm trying my best, but only what I can get is 'ValueError: unsupported bit depth 8 for 3D reference array' error. Tried with different drawing on that screen etc. :C

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [mcve]? Perhaps the display mode is different? Does `surfarray.array2d()` return an error?

Comment: No, it does not. But by using it, I'm still getting only grey image - where grey refers to arrays filled with zeroes in result image. I'll try to figure out how to reproduce it, but It's a big mess (not only by my fault, thankfully), so propably it could be almost impossible to do. I'm still in big concern, why saving image to file works like a charm, but saving to a buffer or np array doesn't...

Comment: You answer actually would work, and it works. Sorry for my stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really stupid... Remember kids, when you're trying to diagnose if image was read correctly with OpenCV, sometimes

```
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

would be your best friend.

Thanks for: [cv2.imshow command doesn't work properly in opencv-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810452/cv2-imshow-command-doesnt-work-properly-in-opencv-python)

No response from the cv2 window gave me concern if displaying is working correctly...